# Please help kotlin error 'No value passed for parameter'

Tags: kotlin

I have a chat application. But I am getting such error in adapters.
Error: No value passed for parameter 'itemView2' What I'm trying to do is to display the item named itemView2 in the xml page. I am not very proficient in Kotlin language. That's why I need help.

This is MessagingAdapter.kt

```
class MessagingAdapter(private val messages: OrderedRealmCollection<Message>, autoUpdate: Boolean,
                   private val context: Context, private val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, var user: User, private val myThumbImg: String,
                   private val selectedItems: LiveData<List<Message>>,
                   private val progressMap: LiveData<Map<String, Int>>, private val audibleState: LiveData<Map<String, AudibleState>>)

: RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Message, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(messages, autoUpdate)
    , StickyHeaderAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private val interaction = context as? Interaction?
private val contactHolderInteraction = context as? ContactHolderInteraction?
private val audibleHolderInteraction = context as? AudibleInteraction?

//timestamps to implement the date header
var timestamps = HashMap<Int, Long>()
var lastTimestampPos = 0


//date header
override fun getHeaderId(position: Int): Long {
    return if (timestamps.containsKey(position)) {
        timestamps[position] ?: 0
    } else 0
}

//date header
override fun onCreateHeaderViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): RecyclerView.ViewHolder? {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_day, parent, false)
    return HeaderHolder(view)
}

//date header
override fun onBindHeaderViewHolder(viewholder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    val mHolder = viewholder as HeaderHolder?

    //if there are no timestamps in this day then hide the header
    //otherwise show it
    val headerId = getHeaderId(position)
    if (headerId == 0L) mHolder?.header?.visibility = View.GONE else {
        val formatted = TimeHelper.getChatTime(headerId)
        mHolder?.header?.text = formatted
    }
}

override fun getItemCount() = messages.size


override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val message = messages[position]
    return message.type
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // check the type of view and return holder
    return getHolderByType(parent, viewType)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(mHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    //get itemView type
    val type = getItemViewType(position)
    val message = messages[position]



    when (type) {
        MessageType.SENT_TEXT -> {
            val sentTextHolder = mHolder as SentTextHolder
            initHolder(sentTextHolder)
            sentTextHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.SENT_IMAGE -> {
            val sentImageHolder = mHolder as SentImageHolder
            initHolder(sentImageHolder)
            sentImageHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.SENT_VOICE_MESSAGE -> {
            val sentVoiceMessageHolder = mHolder as SentVoiceMessageHolder
            initHolder(sentVoiceMessageHolder)
            initAudibleHolder(sentVoiceMessageHolder)
            sentVoiceMessageHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.SENT_VIDEO -> {
            val sentVideoMessageHolder = mHolder as SentVideoMessageHolder
            initHolder(sentVideoMessageHolder)
            sentVideoMessageHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.SENT_FILE -> {
            val sentFileHolder = mHolder as SentFileHolder
            initHolder(sentFileHolder)
            sentFileHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.SENT_AUDIO -> {
            val sentAudioHolder = mHolder as SentAudioHolder
            initHolder(sentAudioHolder)
            initAudibleHolder(sentAudioHolder)
            sentAudioHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.SENT_CONTACT -> {
            val sentContactHolder = mHolder as SentContactHolder
            initHolder(sentContactHolder)
            initContactHolder(sentContactHolder)
            sentContactHolder.bind(message, user)
        }

        MessageType.SENT_LOCATION -> {
            val sentLocationHolder = mHolder as SentLocationHolder
            initHolder(sentLocationHolder)
            sentLocationHolder.bind(message, user)
        }

        MessageType.SENT_STICKER -> {
            val sentStickerHolder = mHolder as SentStickerHolder
            initHolder(sentStickerHolder)
            sentStickerHolder.bind(message, user)
        }

        MessageType.RECEIVED_TEXT -> {
            val holder = mHolder as ReceivedTextHolder
            initHolder(holder)
            holder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.RECEIVED_IMAGE -> {
            val receivedImageHolder = mHolder as ReceivedImageHolder
            initHolder(receivedImageHolder)
            receivedImageHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.RECEIVED_VOICE_MESSAGE -> {
            val receivedVoiceMessageHolder = mHolder as ReceivedVoiceMessageHolder
            initHolder(receivedVoiceMessageHolder)
            initAudibleHolder(receivedVoiceMessageHolder)
            receivedVoiceMessageHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.RECEIVED_VIDEO -> {
            val receivedVideoMessageHolder = mHolder as ReceivedVideoMessageHolder
            initHolder(receivedVideoMessageHolder)
            receivedVideoMessageHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.RECEIVED_FILE -> {
            val receivedFileHolder = mHolder as ReceivedFileHolder
            initHolder(receivedFileHolder)
            receivedFileHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.RECEIVED_AUDIO -> {
            val receivedAudioHolder = mHolder as ReceivedAudioHolder
            initHolder(receivedAudioHolder)
            initAudibleHolder(receivedAudioHolder)
            receivedAudioHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.RECEIVED_CONTACT -> {
            val receivedContactHolder = mHolder as ReceivedContactHolder
            initHolder(receivedContactHolder)
            initContactHolder(receivedContactHolder)
            receivedContactHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.RECEIVED_LOCATION -> {
            val receivedLocationHolder = mHolder as ReceivedLocationHolder
            initHolder(receivedLocationHolder)
            receivedLocationHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.SENT_DELETED_MESSAGE -> {
            val sentDeletedMessageHolder = mHolder as SentDeletedMessageHolder
            sentDeletedMessageHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.RECEIVED_DELETED_MESSAGE -> {
            val receivedDeletedMessageHolder = mHolder as ReceivedDeletedMessageHolder
            receivedDeletedMessageHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.GROUP_EVENT -> {
            val groupEventHolder = mHolder as GroupEventHolder
            groupEventHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        MessageType.RECEIVED_STICKER -> {
            val receivedStickerHolder = mHolder as ReceivedStickerHolder
            initHolder(receivedStickerHolder)
            receivedStickerHolder.bind(message, user)
        }
        else -> {
            val notSupportedTypeHolder = mHolder as? NotSupportedTypeHolder
            notSupportedTypeHolder?.bind(message, user)
        }
    }
}

private fun initHolder(baseHolder: BaseHolder) {
    baseHolder.selectedItems = selectedItems
    baseHolder.progressMap = progressMap
    baseHolder.lifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner
    baseHolder.interaction = interaction
}

private fun initAudibleHolder(audibleBase: AudibleBase) {
    audibleBase.audibleInteraction = audibleHolderInteraction
    audibleBase.audibleState = audibleState
}

private fun initContactHolder(contactHolderBase: ContactHolderBase) {
    contactHolderBase.contactHolderInteraction = contactHolderInteraction
}


private fun distinctMessagesTimestamps() {

    for (i in messages.indices) {
        val timestamp = messages[i].timestamp.toLong()
        if (i == 0) {
            timestamps[i] = timestamp
            lastTimestampPos = i
        } else {
            val oldTimestamp = messages[i - 1].timestamp.toLong()
            if (!TimeHelper.isSameDay(timestamp, oldTimestamp)) {
                timestamps[i] = timestamp
                lastTimestampPos = i
            }
        }

    }

}

//update timestamps if needed when a new message inserted
fun messageInserted() {
    val index = messages.size - 1
    val newTimestamp = messages[index].timestamp.toLong()
    if (timestamps.isEmpty()) {
        timestamps[index] = newTimestamp
        lastTimestampPos = index
        return
    }
    val lastTimestamp = timestamps[lastTimestampPos]!!
    if (!TimeHelper.isSameDay(lastTimestamp, newTimestamp)) {
        timestamps[index] = newTimestamp
        lastTimestampPos = index
    }
}


private fun getHolderByType(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    when (viewType) {
        MessageType.DAY_ROW -> return TimestampHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_day, parent, false))
        MessageType.SENT_DELETED_MESSAGE -> return SentDeletedMessageHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_sent_deleted_message, parent, false))
        MessageType.RECEIVED_DELETED_MESSAGE -> return ReceivedDeletedMessageHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_received_deleted_message, parent, false))
        MessageType.SENT_TEXT -> return SentTextHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_sent_message_text, parent, false))
        MessageType.SENT_IMAGE -> return SentImageHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_sent_message_img, parent, false))
        MessageType.RECEIVED_TEXT -> return ReceivedTextHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_received_message_text, parent, false)) //ERROR HERE
        MessageType.RECEIVED_IMAGE -> return ReceivedImageHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_received_message_img, parent, false))
        MessageType.SENT_VOICE_MESSAGE -> return SentVoiceMessageHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_sent_voice_message, parent, false), myThumbImg)
        MessageType.RECEIVED_VOICE_MESSAGE -> return ReceivedVoiceMessageHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_received_message_voice, parent, false))
        MessageType.RECEIVED_VIDEO -> return ReceivedVideoMessageHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_received_message_video, parent, false))
        MessageType.SENT_VIDEO -> return SentVideoMessageHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_sent_message_video, parent, false))
        MessageType.SENT_FILE -> return SentFileHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_sent_file, parent, false))
        MessageType.RECEIVED_FILE -> return ReceivedFileHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_received_file, parent, false))
        MessageType.SENT_AUDIO -> return SentAudioHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_sent_audio, parent, false))
        MessageType.RECEIVED_AUDIO -> return ReceivedAudioHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_received_audio, parent, false))
        MessageType.SENT_CONTACT -> return SentContactHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_sent_contact, parent, false))
        MessageType.RECEIVED_CONTACT -> return ReceivedContactHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_received_contact, parent, false))
        MessageType.SENT_LOCATION -> return SentLocationHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_sent_location, parent, false))
        MessageType.RECEIVED_LOCATION -> return ReceivedLocationHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_received_location, parent, false))
        MessageType.GROUP_EVENT -> return GroupEventHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_group_event, parent, false))
        MessageType.SENT_STICKER -> return SentStickerHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_sent_sticker, parent, false))
        MessageType.RECEIVED_STICKER -> return ReceivedStickerHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_received_sticker, parent, false))
    }
    return NotSupportedTypeHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_not_supported, parent, false))
}


init {
    distinctMessagesTimestamps()
}
```

}

This is ReceivedTextHolder.kt

```
class ReceivedTextHolder(context: Context, itemView: View,itemView2: View) : BaseReceivedHolder(context,itemView) {

private var tvMessageContent: AXEmojiTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_message_content)
private val circleImg: CircleImageView = itemView2.findViewById<View>(R.id.voice_circle_img_text) as CircleImageView

override fun bind(message: Message,user: User) {
    super.bind(message,user)
    tvMessageContent.text = message.content
    loadUserPhoto(user,message.fromId, circleImg)
}
private fun loadUserPhoto(user:User,fromId: String, imageView: ImageView) {

    //if it's a group load the user image
    if (user.isGroupBool && user.group.users != null) {
        val mUser = ListUtil.getUserById(fromId, user.group.users)
        if (mUser != null && mUser.thumbImg != null) {
            Glide.with(context).load(mUser.thumbImg).into(imageView)
        }
    } else {
        if (user.thumbImg != null) Glide.with(context).load(user.thumbImg).into(imageView)
    }
}
```

}

**Please help guys :(**
What I'm trying to do is to display the item named itemView2 in the xml page.

Answer (score 1):

What the error means is that you're trying to call a function that asks for a parameter named `itemView2`, but you didn't pass that parameter. Usually this happens when you provide too few arguments when you call the method.

In this specific case, the method in question is actually the constructor of `ReceivedTextHolder`. As you can see, the constructor is declared to take 3 parameters (`context`, `itemView`, and `itemView2`):

```kotlin
class ReceivedTextHolder(context: Context, itemView: View,itemView2: View)
```

But when you call this constructor, you only give 2 arguments:

```kotlin
return ReceivedTextHolder(context, LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_received_message_text, parent, false)) //ERROR HERE
```

Here, the first argument (`context`) receives the value `context`, and the second argument (`itemView`) receives the value of the expression:

```kotlin
LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row_received_message_text, parent, false)
```

But you're missing the 3rd argument. The 3rd would probably look like the 2nd one. You just need to find and inflate the correct view for that.

Comment: Hi @Joffrey, Thank you for your help.
I'll try this and let you know.
I hope I can. :)